# How can ensure that a function only accepts a positive integer?

Tags: powershell, int

I want to do some basic validation on a user input in PowerShell to ensure a user can only enter a whole integer and does not enter -7 for example. I am not sure how this is done and would appreciate a pointer.

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)][int]$number
```

If a user enters `-$number` this will be accepted. I want it to reject this type of input.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `ValidateRange` for the parameter:

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
[int] $number
```

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847743.aspx):

> ValidateRange Validation Attribute
>
> The ValidateRange attribute specifies a numeric range for each
>           parameter or variable value. Windows PowerShell generates an error
>           if any value is outside that range. In the following example,
>           the value of the Attempts parameter must be between 0 and 10.
>
> ```
> Param
> (
>     [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
>     [ValidateRange(0,10)]
>     [Int]
>     $Attempts
> )
> ```
>
> In the following example, the value of the variable $number must be 
>           between 0 and 10.
>
> ```
> [Int32][ValidateRange(0,10)]$number = 5
> ```

Comment: Based on what's shown here it's not obvious, but to clarify - The ValidateRange(0,10) using [int] type in this example is inclusive of the zero and ten number boundaries.  Therefore, given a value of either 0 or 10 in this example it should be valid and will not generate an error.

Answer (score 12):

Since PowerShell 6.1.0 you kan use ValidateRangeKind to initialize the attribute:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[ValidateRange("Positive")]
[Int] $Number = 5
```

> ValidateRange validation attribute
>
> The ValidateRange attribute specifies a numeric range or a ValidateRangeKind enum value for each parameter or variable value. PowerShell generates an error if any value is outside that range.
>
> The ValidateRangeKind enum allows for the following values:
>
> - Positive - A number greater than zero.
> - Negative - A number less than zero.
> - NonPositive - A number less than or equal to zero.
> - NonNegative - A number greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

In Powershell 5

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
[ValidateScript({$_ -gt 0})]
[Int] $Number = 5
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include the zero, you might simply use the [`[uint]` or `[ulong]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)types (which also give you a larger range of positive numbers):

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)][uint]$number
```